# css `transform` is not working in button

Tags: html, css

I have a button with a icon . The icon is hidden . When I hover on the button the icon appears . `transform` is working fine on the button . But on the text it is not working .

**Code**

```css
        .btn.btn-rolling{
           overflow: hidden;
           position: relative;
        }
        
        .btn.btn-rolling i{
           transform: translateX(-30px); 
        }
        
        .btn.btn-rolling span{
           transform: translateX(-30px); 
        }
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-rolling"><i class="fa facebook"></i><span>Click me</span></button>
```

Comment: Where is hover effect?

Comment: on the button . `.btn-rolling:hover`

Comment: try to create fiddle

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yezimawaxe/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @muhaimin There is not hover effect you given in your jsbin source code.

Comment: @muhaimin you need something like: http://jsfiddle.net/o1L6p20d/2/ ?

Comment: HOVER effect isn't matter . matter is to transform .

Answer (score 0):

Hi you don't need to `transform` the text. If you are adding the property to `button` so `span` inside the `button` will also have the transform property.

Look This :

http://jsfiddle.net/Saiyam/o1L6p20d/3/

Answer (score 0):

This will work by using `table-properties`.